# Ownership issues when dealing with abstract base classes as members

Tags: c++, pointers, constructor, virtual, ownership

When passing classes as arguments in constructors I end up passing pointers in most cases. The main reason for that is I have to pass abstract classes that cannot be instantiated, and as a reference cannot be null I do not really have a choice...

Here is an example :

```
// Abstract class A
class A { 
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

class B : public A {
    void foo();
};

class C {
public:
    C(A* a) : _a(a) {};
private:
    A* _a;
};
```

In some cases I want `C` to take care of the `A` object `_a` is pointing at (delete it when deleted), in other cases I want `C` to delete `_a` without deleting the `A` object.

What are the best practices to have a sound programming methodology ?

Comment: Use references -- they really shine when it comes to expressing 'view only -- no taking ownership'. If you really need a null value, `boost::optional<T&>` is available.

Comment: I cannot use references on abstract classes unfortunately. Boost features are certainly awesome but I cannot use it at work for now. Is there any pure C++ feature to solve the issue ?

Comment: You certainly [can](http://ideone.com/fVwq7) use references.

Comment: The paragraph that starts with *In some cases* does not seem to make much sense. How would you delete `_a` without deleting the `A` object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `shared_ptr` to express shared ownership, and `unique_ptr` to express unique ownership.  If you are sure that the lifetime of `C` is bounded by the lifetime of the `A` object (or another object owning `A`) then you can use a reference, or a `shared_ptr` with a nil deleter.

Comment: +1 But if you are not sure, a reference is not an option. A reference implies that the class is not responsible, so you have to be sure of at least that much. A `shared_ptr` is a better option if you are unsure.